# SwiftUI SidebarListStyle inside of NavigationView's Style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

i'm new with SwiftUI.
My goal is to make `List` which listStyle is SidebarListStyle just exactly like this
[first][1]

and here's my code

```
            List{
            MyProfile()
            Section(header:
                        Text("친구 102")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            ){
                FriendsList()
            } // Section
        } // List
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
```

But if i put this code inside `NavigationView`, listStyle changes without my intention like this
[second][2]

and code

```
        NavigationView{
        List{
            MyProfile()
            Section(header:
                        Text("친구 102")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            ){
                FriendsList()
            } // Section
        } // List
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
```

any help?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/awX3H.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMBZn.png

Comment: Can you write MyProfile and FriendList code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **StackNavigationViewStyle**

```
NavigationView{
        List{
            MyProfile()
            Section(header:
                        Text("친구 102")
                        .font(.footnote)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            ){
                FriendsList()
            } // Section
        } // List
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }
  .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```